Hello World for jaxtyping?
I can't find any instructions or tutorials for getting started with jaxtyping. I tried the simplest possible program and it fails to parse. I'm on Python 3.11. I don't see anything on GitHub jaxtyping project about an upper bound (lower bound is Python 3.9) and it looks like it's actively maintained (last commit was 8 hours ago).
What step am I missing?
jaxtyping==0.2.36
numpy==2.1.3
torch==2.5.1
typeguard==4.4.1

(It seems like numpy is required for some reason even though I'm not using it)
from typeguard import typechecked
from jaxtyping import Float
from torch import Tensor


@typechecked
def matmul(a: Float[Tensor, "m n"], b: Float[Tensor, "n p"]) -> Float[Tensor, "m p"]:
    """
    Matrix multiplication of two 2D arrays.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError("This function is not implemented yet.")

(venv) dspyz@dspyz-desktop:~/helloworld$ python matmul.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/matmul.py", line 6, in <module>
    @typechecked
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_decorators.py", line 221, in typechecked
    retval = instrument(target)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_decorators.py", line 72, in instrument
    instrumentor.visit(module_ast)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 598, in visit_Module
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 498, in generic_visit
    node = super().generic_visit(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 494, in generic_visit
    value = self.visit(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 672, in visit_FunctionDef
    with self._use_memo(node):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 556, in _use_memo
    new_memo.return_annotation = self._convert_annotation(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 582, in _convert_annotation
    new_annotation = cast(expr, AnnotationTransformer(self).visit(annotation))
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 355, in visit
    new_node = super().visit(node)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 421, in visit_Subscript
    [self.visit(item) for item in node.slice.elts],
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 421, in <listcomp>
    [self.visit(item) for item in node.slice.elts],
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 355, in visit
    new_node = super().visit(node)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dspyz/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/_transformer.py", line 474, in visit_Constant
    expression = ast.parse(node.value, mode="eval")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    m p
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


It looks like this fails because jaxtyping only imports numpy if you have it installed (this is a bug in jaxtyping, and I'd suggest reporting it). You could probably fix that by installing numpy.

Is this question asking for a jaxtyping example, or is it about the specific error you are getting? If it's the former, I'll vote to close it as lacking focus. If it's the latter, please [edit] it so that it focus on that one problem only.

@jakevdp Oops, I included too much in my command-line history. Removed. I was asking about the error I got next.

@InSync The question is "How do I anything jaxtyping?" and then I'm showing what happens what goes wrong when I try to do what I think is the obvious thing but also there's no setting-up/hello-world anywhere that I can find. If I'm doing the wrong thing altogether than I don't mind an answer of the form: "Don't try to do that, do this instead". If I'm basically doing the right thing, then the question is how do I fix the error I'm getting

If stackoverflow is meant to be a useful repository for people who have similar issues to get answers than anyone who googles jaxtyping and SyntaxError will hopefully come across this and hopefully be able to find an answer (when I google it currently I find nothing useful and chatgpt just hallucinates non-existent functions I should be calling instead)

(jaxtyping author here)
Sadly this is a known bug in typeguard v4. It's been around forever and hasn't been fixed. (At a technical level: typeguard v4 attempts to load and reparse the source code of your function, but it doesn't properly parse all type annotations.)
I use typeguard==2.13.3 myself, which seems to be pretty robust.
EDIT: removed some other suggested workarounds. These turned out not to, well, work. For now I just recommend pinning to that earlier version of typeguard.

You are running into the issue reported here: https://github.com/patrick-kidger/jaxtyping/issues/80
You can work around this by installing typeguard version 3.0, but given how long this bug has remained open without any real fix, I suspect the best conclusion is that jaxtyping should no longer be considered compatible with typeguard.
